# Utilize scanners to fill object arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I'm fairly new to programming and I recently wrote something to utilize a scanner class to fill an object array from a text file. Essentially, I can re-write this text file or add new info and won't have to change the code. I suppose my question is this: is there an easier/more preferred method to doing this? I'm trying to learn the coding nuances.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ImportTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    Scanner s = null;
    Scanner k = null;
    ArrayList myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList myList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList myList3 = new ArrayList<Student>();
    try 
    {
        s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testMe.txt")));
        while (s.hasNext()) 
        {
            myList.add(s.nextLine()); 
        }
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (s != null) 
        {
            s.close();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("My List 1:");
    for(int i=0; i<myList.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i+". "+myList.get(i));
    }
    for(int x=0; x<myList.size(); x++)
    {
        try 
        {
            k = new Scanner(myList.get(x).toString());
            while (k.hasNext()) 
            {
                myList2.add(k.next()); 
            }
        } 
        finally 
        {
            if (k != null) 
            {
                k.close();
            }
        }
        String name;
        int age;
        double money;
        name=myList2.get(0).toString();
        age=Integer.parseInt(myList2.get(1).toString());
        money=Double.parseDouble(myList2.get(2).toString());
        Student myStudent=new Student(name, age, money);
        myList3.add(myStudent);
        myList2.clear();
    }
    System.out.println("Test of list object: ");
    for(int i=0; i<myList3.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i+". "+myList3.get(i).toString());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would read the file line by line and parse every line directly. This way you do not need 3 lists, 2 scanners and multiple iterations:

```
String line = "";
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
while( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
   String[] tmp = line.split("\\s+");  //split line by spaces

   //this needs bounds & error checking etc.
   students.add(new Student(tmp[0], Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]), Double.parseDouble(tmp[2])));
}
```

In Java 7 you can use the [new file functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) to read all lines at once:

```
List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines("test.txt", Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Do not forget to close the reader or use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) (since java 1.7)

Comment: Yes, working inside the scanner while-loop simplifies your code, removing the need for ArrayList. I must caution that any heavy duty work done inside the loop can create I/O performance bottleneck in a large scale application.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, `testMe.txt` file contains Student information which are *name*, *age*, *money*, and you want read those values.

Best way to do it is you should serialize your *Student* objects into the the `testMe.txt` with the help of `ObjectOutputStream`. As well you can read those value using `ObjectInputStream`, so in this way you can able to get `Student` objects itself(no need to hnadle `String`).

In case you do want to serialize the data into file, you should store the data in some predefined format like as comma(,) or semi-colon(;) seperated.

For Example -

```
emp1, 24, 20000
emp emp2, 25, 24000
emp3, 26, 26000
```

In this case while reading the string you can split it with seperation character and get the actual information.

*Code snippet*:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
...
try(scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testMe.txt")))){        
    while (scanner.hasNext()){
        String data[] = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
        Student student = new Student(data[0],data[1],data[2]);
        students.add(student);
    }
}
```

`Try-with-resource` will automatically handle the resouce, you dont need to explicitly close it. This features available in java since 1.7.